# Examples of good system testing reports?

Tags: testing, system-testing

I'm writing some reports for software system test results, and I'm looking for inspiration. Are there any really good examples out there of test reports that I can model mine after?

Note that this is system testing, not unit testing. I'm taking test cases, running them through my system in a variety of ways, and doing both truth and regression testing on the results.

I need a good way to visualize all that information and make it useful.

Answer (score 1):

[Checkout](http://abeautifulwww.com/2008/09/08/20-useful-visualization-libraries/) some of the [data visualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_visualization) examples and the frameworks that generated them. Whichever you choose keep below points in mind (based on my own experience in generating reports for test automation initiative at my company)

- Make provision to provide the results in Excel format so that stakeholders can use it in whichever way they want i.e. graph it, derive some info out of it, email it etc
- Show the Trend history at feature level and also individual test level
- Numbers matter than charts